# HTC Evo 4g LTe Jellybean (JB) charge only

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I just flashed a new stock JB ROM from viper boy over at xda.

What happened to the Connect to PC in the settings window? I can see my HTC Evo 4g LTE as a disk drive and media exchange, but it has no option for charge only. What mode do I need to be in to run cmd commands on my JB phone? Every tutorial for cmd says charge only.

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding, you are saying that there is a cmd commnd to enable charging, and this is what you are looking for. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this shouldn't be here, this should have been asked at the XDA thread itself. With all the tweaks they make to their ROM, it would have been a good idea.

Second, with MTP, there is no need for Charge only. The SD card and Phone Storage is always available when you are connected. "Charge Only" was relevant when you were on ICS or GB and you had UMS (USB Mass Storage).

Answer (score 1):

As it is two questions in one, you need two answers:

1. To **run commands via ADB,** you do not need to set that mode now - you just need to have USB debugging enabled, and the cmd commands will work.
   Just remember that having USB debugging enabled could warrant a security risk as it may allow someone that has stolen your phone to access it's data without having to unlock it, but as you seem to have had it enabled previously, then I believe you should understand the risks.
2. Concerning the **USB connection mode:** In the old Android version, that mode caused issues (due to manufacturer modifications), since jellybean, Android uses MTP, so that option became redundant.

Comment: Thanks, great site and even better contributors.. Merry Christmas.